# How do I get all the inputs from the same form field in django? (The form field is in a loop in the HTML thus appears more than once)

Tags: python, django, forms, field, sudoku

I'm trying to get all the inputs from the same form field which displayed in the HTML twice since it's in a loop (as in this example). Is there a way I can do it? Below are the codes:

HTML

```
def home(request):
    nums = [[3, "", 2, 7, 5, 6, 1, 4, 9],
             [1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8],
             [6, 7, 9, 1, 4, 8, 2, 3, 5],
             [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7],
             [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 3, 1, 2],
             [7, 9, 8, 3, 1, "", 4, 5, 6],
             [5, 2, 1, 6, 7, 3, 9, 8, 4],
             [8, 3, 7, 9, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1],
             [9, 6, 4, 5, 8, 1, 7, 2, 3]]
    context = {'nums': nums}

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SForm(request.POST)
        context['form'] = form
        if form.is_valid():
            num = form.cleaned_data.get('num')
    else:
        form = SForm()
        context['form'] = form

    context['range'] = range(9)
    return render(request, 's/home.html', context)
```

Forms.py

```
class SForm(forms.Form):
    num = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=9, label=False)
```

HTML.py

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" name="s_form">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {% for row in nums %}
      <tr>
        {% for col in row %}
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"9" %}
          <br>
        {% endif %}
        {% if col != "" %}
        <span id="{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }} - {{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ col }}</span>
        {% else %}
        <span id="{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }} - {{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ form }}</span>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}

  <div class="container"><button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="button">Submit</button></div>
</form>
{{ num }}
{% endblock %}
```

However, the problem I see is that the form is treated as one. After I post the input, the 2 integer fields return the same value.. (screenshot below)

[image] (before post)
[image] (after post)

Anyone knows how I can get both input values from the same field..?Or if there's a way to use multiple fields? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "prefix" arg for form instances

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64030787/django-forms-create-a-form-for-each-object-in-model-and-then-save-to-the-corr/64037547#64037547)

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex! I thought about prefix, but am not very familiar with how to implement that in the view.. So currently I'm going with just using <input> tag. But once I want to give it a try, I'll let you know what I found. :) Thank you!!